# Question related to Directed Acyclic Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

In an assignment I got a question, "Show that the strongly connected component of a DAG is also a DAG."

Now I wasn't able to solve this. The problem I faced with this question was that the DAG is itself not a strongly connected directed graph then how can it have strongly connected components. The only strongly connected components it can have are itself the nodes. Was this the answer to the question.

Comment: The question statement  says "**the** strongly connected component." The bold word is odd as a directed graph can have many strongly connected components (in the DAG case, every vertex is a strongly connected component as you see). So are you sure what we are thinking of as a strongly connected component is the same as what your instructor is thinking of?

Comment: "Show that the strongly connected component of a DAG is also a DAG" This is the exact question.

Comment: But my point is what is the definition of *strongly connected component* that is being used? If it is the usual one (maximal strongly connected subgraph), then I guess the question is just worded poorly and you are correct in that any strongly connected component is just a single vertex.

Comment: The question was indeed misstated. The instructor has made us change the question to: "Show that a connected component of a DAG is also a DAG." Can you also help me out in this case. What I thought in this case was that we can show we have a sink and a source and as it's a connected component it'll be a DAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to both of your initial and renewed questions: 
Note that there is no directed circuit in a directed acyclic graph, hence a subgraph of a directed acyclic graph also has no directed circuit, and hence acyclic. Therefore, a stronly component or just a component must be also a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: Won't we have to prove that the connected component contains a source and a sink?

Comment: No need to do it, as our concern is the existence of circuit.